# where using alias of aggregate

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions, alias

This query

```
select r1.name, count(stars) as reviewCount 
from (reviewer r1 join reviewer r2 using(rID)) join rating using(rID) 
group by r1.name;
```

Yields the following output

```
    +------------------+--------------+
    | name             | reviewCount |
    +------------------+--------------+
    | Ashley White     |            1 |
    | Brittany Harris  |            3 |
    | Chris Jackson    |            3 |
    | Daniel Lewis     |            1 |
    | Elizabeth Thomas |            2 |
    | James Cameron    |            1 |
    | Mike Anderson    |            1 |
    | Sarah Martinez   |            2 |
    +------------------+--------------+
```

i want to list users who have reviewCount > 3, something like below

```
+------------------+--------------+
| name             | reviewCount |
+------------------+--------------+
| Brittany Harris  |            3 |
| Chris Jackson    |            3 |
+------------------+--------------+
```

i have tried using where and having clause but they result in `Empty set (0.01 sec)`

```
select r1.name, count(stars) as reviewCount 
from (reviewer r1 join reviewer r2 using(rID)) join rating using(rID) 
group by r1.name
having reviewCount > 3;
```

What is it that i am missing?

edit1 : refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48881904/unknown-column-while-using-alias-mysql/48882277#48882277)  for sample data to test

edit 2: Also can anyone suggest how can i write this query without using count and having

Comment: *"i want to list users who have reviewCount > 3" -- `3` is not `> 3`.

Comment: `WHERE` applies to individual records, `HAVING` applies to the values computed after grouping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is actually correct but your query needs a little modification. You need to use `>=` rather than `>`

```
HAVING reviewCount >= 3;
```

I'd rather use the aggregated column than it's alias since it will work on most RDBMS.

```
HAVING count(stars) >= 3
```